# How to autostart nanoGallery?

Tags: javascript, html, image-gallery, nanogallery

I have an image gallery that is displayed using
[nanogallery js plugin](http://nanogallery.brisbois.fr/)

And I need to autostart it when page is loaded.

My Code

```
<script>

    function myThumbnailDisplayEffect($elt, item, eltNumber) {
        $elt.css({'transform-origin': 'top right', 'rotate': '10deg', 'top':'-30px'});
        $elt.delay(eltNumber*30).transition({ 'rotate': '0deg', 'opacity':'1', top:'0px'},700);
        $elt.find('.nanoGalleryThumbnailContainer').click();

    }



    function loadGallery(){
        jQuery("#gallery").nanoGallery({thumbnailLabel:{display:false},
            colorSchemeViewer:'light',
            viewer:{display:false},
            thumbnailHoverEffect:'imageOpacity50',
            thumbnailWidth: 200,
            thumbnailHeight: 133,
            lazyBuild:'loadData',
            thumbnailLazyLoad:true,
            fnThumbnailDisplayEffect:myThumbnailDisplayEffect

        });
    }

    $(document).ready(loadGallery());
</script>
```

How to do that...?
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What do you mean autostart? What is it suppose to do when it autostarts?

Comment: after image gallery is loaded I want to simulate a click on a first element to show it in "fullscreen" mode

Comment: do you have any example code? what is the first element

Comment: I inserted the code in the question

Answer (score 0):

you can simulate a click event on the first element. you will need to add an ID or Class or data attribute to the div that holds the first image and then using jquery you can do this:

```
var firstElement = $('.nanoGalleryContainer').children()[0];
$(firstElement).trigger('mouseenter').trigger('click');
```

Comment: You will need to put that code in the document ready function after the loadGallery() function

Comment: Also what is the container holding you images that will be clicked on? My code is targeting the first div within the container container with class .nanoGalleryContainer

Answer (score 0):

You could use deep linking to implement this using URL parameters.

For example: http://nanogallery.brisbois.fr/nanogallery_demo3.html#nanogallery/nanoGalleryExample/5870136791457517345/5871255268929586546

To enable this feature, you have to set the plugin parameter **locationHash** to **true**.

More examples: http://nanogallery.brisbois.fr/nanogallery_demo3.html